# ASP.NET LoginForm change LoginButton cssClass onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code, frontend(just the relevant code):

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser">

<td align="right" colspan="2">
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" CommandName="Login" Text="Log Ind" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
</td>
```

And then in the backend code i wish to change the backgroundcolor of the LoginButton when it has been clicked. But I can't seem to get a hold of the button in my ValidateUser function?

I only have the following options:

```
Login1.LoginButtonImageUrl
Login1.LoginButtonStyle
Login1.LoginButtonText
Login1.LoginButtonType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not have or not access all properties on an asp control, that in this case is inside the login form, the trick is to **find it first inside this form** and then do what you like. In your case the code will be as:

```
    // first find and capture the control
    var oLoginButton = (Button)Login1.FindControl("LoginButton");

    // now you have all propeties of the asp.net control
    oLoginButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```